# Perceptron on multi-dimensional tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, perceptron

I'm trying to use Perceptron to reduce a tensor of size: `[1, 24, 768]` to another tensor with size of `[1, 1, 768]`. The only way I could use was to first reshape the input tensor to `[1, 1, 24*768]` and then pass it through linear layers. I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way of this transformation --other than using RNNs cause I do not want to use that. Are there other methods generally for the transformation that I want to make? Here is my code for doing the above operation:

```
lin = nn.Linear(24*768, 768)

# x is in shape of [1, 24, 768]
# out is in shape of [1, 1, 768]
x = x.view(1,1,-1)
out = lin(x)
```

Comment: This is the way to do it with linear layers, but you should reshape to [1, 24*768] I think, I don't understand why you would keep 3 dimensions. And what's wrong with this approach ?

Comment: @trialNerror Correct. That's why I did, and I don't suppose that it is wrong (I didn't say that's wrong). I was just wondering if there's any other method (other than what I did) for doing this transformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the broadcasting is what's bothering you, you could use a [`nn.Flatten`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Flatten.html) to do it:

```
>>> m = nn.Sequential(
...    nn.Flatten(),
...    nn.Linear(24*768, 768))

>>> x = torch.rand(1, 24, 768)

>>> m(x).shape
torch.Size([1, 768])
```

If you really want the extra dimension you can unsqueeze the tensor on `axis=1`:

```
>>> m(x).unsqueeze(1).shape
torch.Size([1, 1, 768])
```

Comment: That sounds very true. I also did this: like flattening the input tensor and then passing it through the perception. I'm just wondering about other ways of doing this. Are there any other methods (other than what I used --you suggested) to make this transformation?

Comment: I've provided you with an alternative, I'm not sure what you mean by other methods? I are you looking for something *shorter*? There's only way to have fully connected layers, and that's with `nn.Linear`...

Comment: Correct. The method that I have posted above is, in fact, flattening the input tensor, then using a linear layer to do the transformation (the same as you suggested). By other methods, I meant other commonly-done stuff that can do this transformation. For example, I know that one way to do this transformation is taking an average over elements of the input tensor and then passing the resulting tensor to linear layer (that's what some people do). I marked your answer as "accepted" since I think flattening is the most common thing that people do when they want to do such transformations.

Comment: If you are taking a global average you wouldn't be performing the same operation: it would ignore any spatial information in the vector, while a FC layer would take every possible combination in account. So it all depends on what you're looking to do.

Comment: the input tensors are representations of some sentences which contain context. So, what some people commonly do in NLP area, is to average all of these representations to get a representation for the document (i.e., sequence of sentences). That's why I took a global average on these tensors which reduces it from shape: [1, 24, 768] to [1, 1, 768].